# Selenium tests do not run. No matter how basic the test is, and it also displays a "Process Timed out Error"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently debugging an error made by My Selenium2 test case. Made on a Ubuntu OS.
The version for Selenium server that I'm currently using is 2.28.0.
The processes I've done so far:

1. Reinstalled Netbeans IDE
   Current Version 7.4
2. Installed Plugins
   Version: 1.0 Source: 1359458324_org-netbeans-modules-selenium-php.nbm, Certified Plugins, org-netbeans-modules-selenium-server.nbm

   - Selenium Module for PHP
     Selenium testing framework for web application
   - JUnit
     Includes the JUnit unit testing library and corresponding library definitions. 3.x and 4.x versions are both included.
   - Selenium Server
     Selenium Server control
     Modules installed: Selenium Module for PHP, JUnit, Selenium Server
3. Install Java
   Java Version: 1.8.0_31
4. Installed PHPUnit 
   PHPUnit Version: 4.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann

System Details:
ubuntu 12.04 LTS

The code for my selenium test:

```
class newSeleneseTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {

public function setUp() {
    $this->setBrowser("firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://google.com/");
}

public function testMyTestCase() {
    $this->url("http://google.com/");
}

}
```

The error that's eating my soul:

```
Time: 45.2 seconds, Memory: 4.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) newSeleneseTest::testMyTestCase
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Process timed out after waiting for 45000 ms.
java.lang.InterruptedException

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

That's about what I can share so far.

Comment: For any of these basic problems, i suggest you to get the latest version of selenium jars. Just give a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, finally got this question solved.
It was not a matter of modules, plugins, codes, and selenium version that solved this problem for me. Downloading xampp and starting it's services did.
Once you have downloaded Xampp, you should stop the server service in Selenium. In my case I used netbeans as my IDE. Once I have started the xampp service, and restarted the Selenium service on my Netbeans, thankfully it worked. So there. If anyone encounters the same problem as me. I hope this will help.

UPDATE (Fevrier 4, 2014)

If it is still not working, try re-installing firefox. I don't know what's happening now, it was debugged by my friend. As of now Selenium is working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

It "appears" that your code is using version 1.0 of Selenium.   You should find something newer to work with.  Most likely that is your problem.

[Selenese](http://www.softwaretestingmentor.com/selenium-tutorials/what-is-selenese/) is the protocol that was in place before Selenium 2.0 introduced webdriver [wire-protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!, I'll try using a newer version of selenium.

Comment: It might not necessary be the version of Selenium you are using.  The problem might be that the PHPUnit thing is using the older soon to be deprecated selenium classes?   It says on the phpunit site:  The only supported scenario of PHPUnit_Selenium is that of a Selenium 2.x server. The server can be accessed through the classic Selenium RC Api, already present in 1.x, or with the WebDriver API (partially implemented) from PHPUnit_Selenium 1.2.   "Classic rc api" is definitely code for "the old stuff".   Your milage may vary on that.

Comment: So it's probably my selenium classes that is making my tests perform a time out? I have no idea as to what I should do.

Also, I tried to change my selenium server previously it was 2.28, now it's currently 2.44. With the change everytime I run a selenium test this error comes out.
    PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: /home/devtraining/.netbeans/7.4/modules/ext/selenium/selenium-server-2.28.0.jar (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: It looks like there are some non-Selenese, Selenium 2.x examples here:  https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/tree/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCase   .  Sorry I am not a php programmer and so I can't help more.

Comment: That is alright :). The mere fact that you tried to help me is enough for me. Thanks! Update, I'm still working on it. Probably has something to do with some of my modules. But I don't know what.